# SVN Switch all maven sub modules in one action on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

i have a maven project that contains sub modules like this :

    `=> parent-project
        =>module1
            =>pom1.xml
        => module2
            =>pom2.xml 
   => pom.xml`

I checkout the parent from svn and then i import all the submodules using the "import maven projects" on eclipse, but when i do this on the parent i have to do it also on each sub maven module.
I know eclipse doesn't handle well this but is there a way to do it like only once on the parent project ?
If there is no eclipse solution, may be another tool ?
Best Regards

Comment: No, when you switch on the parent, all child will switch also. That is if your Eclipse, M2E and SVN and everything is uptodate

Comment: I had to reimport all maven module, i didn't even need to switch them. Maybe it's because i'm using SVN 1.8+